# How to translate text from English to German

Tags: javascript, jquery, language-translation, google-translator-toolkit, translators

I would like to translate the text from English to German. Transliterate is just translating from English to another language except for German language.How can I translate from English to German?

Here is the code i am using :

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Load the Google Transliterate API
        google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
        });

        function onLoad() {
            var options = {
                sourceLanguage: 'en',
                destinationLanguage: ['hi', 'kn', 'ml', 'ta', 'te'],
                shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
                transliterationEnabled: true
            };

            // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
            // options.
            var control =
                new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

            // Enable transliteration in the textfields with the given ids.
            var ids = ["transl1", "transl2"];
            control.makeTransliteratable(ids);

            // Show the transliteration control which can be used to toggle between
            // English and Hindi and also choose other destination language.
            control.showControl('translControl');
        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>Type in Indian languages (Press Ctrl+g to toggle between English and Hindi)</center>
    <div id='translControl'></div>
    <br>Title : <input type='textbox' id="transl1" />
    <br>Body<br><textarea id="transl2" style="width:600px;height:200px"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is right code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Load the Google Transliterate API
        google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
        });

        function onLoad() {
            var options = {
                sourceLanguage: 'en',
                destinationLanguage: ['hi', 'kn', 'ml', 'ta', 'te'],
                shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
                transliterationEnabled: true
            };

            // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
            // options.
            var control =
                new
            google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

            // Enable transliteration in the textfields with the given ids.
            var ids = ["transl1", "transl2"];
            control.makeTransliteratable(ids);

            // Show the transliteration control which can be used to toggle 
            between
            // English and Hindi and also choose other destination language.
            control.showControl('translControl');
        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <center>Type in Indian languages (Press Ctrl+g to toggle between English and Hindi)</center> -->
    <div id='translControl'></div>
    <br />Title:
    <input type='textbox' id="transl1" />
    <br />Body
    <br />
    <textarea id="transl2" style="width:600px;height:200px"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```